# How to paste on colunm based on its name

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code to paste content in my table, but I want it to work correctly when I'm not in a specific cell in the current row, because it always returns a fixed cell number to paste the content, so I would like help to know how I modify this code so that it pastes the contents in the current line but instead of using `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3)` , use something that would: Paste in the cell of the current row that is part of the column [Plano de Contas].

My current code:

```
Sub COLAR_CC() 

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Table for reference:
[image]

Comment: Hardcode the column instead of using an offset? `ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 4)`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Sadly i cant mark your comment as correct answer haha, but my thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this may start you off:
[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub sub1()
  Dim icol&
  icol = FindCol("ColTwo") ' find column
  Cells(3, icol) = "Got it"
End Sub

Function FindCol&(txt$) ' find column
  Dim iErr&
  On Error Resume Next
  FindCol = Rows(1).Find(txt, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext, True).Column
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then Stop ' handle error
  On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```